# Swagger UI REST URL suffix (.json) 404 error

Tags: ruby, json, rest, swagger-ui, ruby-grape

I have deployed a test Grape REST API and I am trying to test it with Swagger UI.

The problem is that when Swagger UI loads the API specification it adds parenthesis to the suffix: http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/todos(.json)

This causes a 404 error since (.json) suffix is not valid.

The URL it calls should look like this: http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/todos

Or this: http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/todos.json

How can I fix this?

[My Swagger UI installation](http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/#!/todos/GET_version_todos_json)

More valid routes:

http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/todos/1

http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/items/1

http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/todos/1/items

http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/todos/1.json

http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/items/1.json

http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/v1/todos/1/items.json

Comment: As you can see in the JSON document describing the API, the `(.json)` is added to all routes of the API: http://arcane-shore-2642.herokuapp.com/api/swagger_doc/todos.json

Can you please provide exemplary definitions of your API routes?

Comment: Sure @croeck, I just added other routes. I set up Swagger because it seems to be an easy way for others developers to test my API. Please let me know if you know another easy way to document and test my API. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry if it came out wrong, but I actually wanted to see your definition of the API routes in your Ruby code. Maybe you could also show the corresponding `add_swagger_documentation` lines. I assume there is something mixed. Which versions of the gems and Swagger UI do you use?

Comment: Hey! Did you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem today. It's because original API spec data came from `grape-swagger` gem has the "(.json)" (or format) suffix.

```
{
  apiVersion: "0.1",
  swaggerVersion: "1.2",
  resourcePath: "/hotels",
  produces: [
  "application/json"
  ],
  apis: [
  {
    path: "/hotels.{format}",
    operations: [

  ...
```

There's a configuration setting `hide_format` to the `add_swagger_documentation` which can hide the format suffix. However, option `hide_format` still has issue in latest released version of `grape-swagger` (0.10.1) with latest `grape` (0.12.0).

So we need to specify the developing `grape-swagger` and then set `hide_format`.

Gemfile

```
gem 'grape-swagger', github: "tim-vandecasteele/grape-swagger"
```

Your root API

```
add_swagger_documentation hide_format: true
```